# How do I stop Xcode from launching simulator upside down and launch landscape by default?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios-simulator

I'm coding my first spritekit game, and every time I launch the simulator it launches the simulator upside down.

Code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scene = GameScene.newGameScene()
        
        // Present the scene
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.presentScene(scene)
        
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

}

----
```

Pictures:

> [image: ss1]
>
> [image: ss2]
>
> [image: ss3]

Query: How do I stop XCode from launching simulator upside down, and launch landscape by default?

Comment: Check the General tab settings of your target under that check the Device Orientation settings.

Comment: Updated screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your `simulator settings` once. As the image attached below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I will re-do the orientation in the simulator as @matt metioned.  I will accept your answer.   Thanks again